# Query not performing - nothing outputting from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a forum type page and I am using a tutorial to help me. The tutorial is all in mysql, so it is outdated, but I have been able to change everything to this point. I'm not sure why, but I am having a horrible time with this code. I first started trying to do it correctly by making a prepared statement, but it would not work at all. Now I am trying to do a basic query to get something, but with the following code, I get the else statement - `echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";`

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

//Start Here
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM forum_topics category_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."'LIMIT 1");
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }
    foreach($sql as $row) {
        $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM forum_posts category_id='".$cid."' AND topic_id='".$tid."'");
        foreach($sql2 as $row2) {
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}
```

Does anyone see what is wrong?? If someone wants, I can add in the prepared statement I was trying to do.

I am posting this, this is the screen shot of what I am trying to replicate of the video.

[image]

Comment: this should be throwing you an error `$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;` that's... if you're checking for them that is.

Comment: please use prepared queries with bound parameters for variable queries... there is enough sql injectable code in the world, you dont need to add more

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just fixed that, but it didn't help show anything.

Comment: @Orangepill I had this in a prepared statement like my post says. I tried to do it the right way first, but after spending 10 hours on this small amount of code, it was not working  so I tried this basic query to see if it will work and it still won't. The db tables are correct. I will add my prepared statement that I had to show that as well.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get this error for my numrows line .... `$numrows = $sql->num_rows;`  `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object i`

Comment: that's because you're using a procedural style to connect with, then an object oriented method using `num_rows`.

Comment: When I change I get this error  `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ` with this code `$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);`

Comment: real hard to say at this point as to which body of code you're modifying and it just confuses things for me here.

Comment: I'm just trying to get this to work for now, so the top one. My initial question. I'll take the other out.

Comment: also make sure you did start the session. I don't know if you did include `session_start();` within pages using sessions.

Comment: Yea, I have a core init file that starts a session when I include it on the page which I did. You can see when I try to start another one... `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() `

Comment: Ps: Look for another tutorial: This one is teaching you how to write code without preventing SQL Injection. Line 32 to 35 are dangerous to use.

Comment: Can I just use POST then?

Comment: the mysqli_num_rows error is because your query is not valid... make sure your query runs on the database via console or myphpadmin or whatever client access you have to the database. If it does then the problem is that you didn't call mysqli::select_db

Comment: You need to give four parameter inside mysqli_connect(), but I only see one. What is your database username and database name?

Comment: I took my connection out. I have the real connection in my file

Comment: What is $stmt?? I don't see any initialization of this in your code. Also num_rows is not mysqli function. Did you check proper guideline?